# What is the maximum damage possible from Silent Moons Enchant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How high can the damage on Silent Moons Enchant get? Can it get higher than ice/fire/lightning enchant damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects),

Silent Moons' base magnitude is 10, same as the Fire / Frost / Shock enchants.

Comment: It does have a better charge/use ratio though.  So it'll last 3x as long, roughly

Comment: @yx ah awesome. I was wondering the point of it if there were no advantages over normal elemental enchants. Thanks.

Comment: What is meant by **when the moon is out**? Does it work only at night, or do you have to be under the moon, that is, outdoors? Does the weather have to be clear, so that, you know, the moons are "out"?

Comment: @Bora I have no idea! Why not ASK A QUESTION? :)

Comment: I can ask questions only when the moon is out :)

Comment: @RavenDreamer - your link does not contain an entry for Silent Moons Enchant.  I'm not a Skyrim player, so it may be called something else, but I just wanted to confirm that you put the correct link in.

Comment: @Jason its there, under weapon effects, its called Light Damage

Answer (score -1):

Well, according to one wiki the silent moons enchant is broken as of a recent patch and doesn't actually work, despite the visible animation of green energy around the target (seen at night).

Another wiki does not state this so I can't confirm that much.

Comment: I'm not sure what any of this has to do with the question being asked.